Is it possible to ping the duplicate closer with an @comment?
In Prevent package from being installed on old Python versions, I attempt to comment to the dupe-hammerer by typing a comment starting with @KarlNechtel. As I'm typing their username, it doesn't auto-complete as usual, because Karl was not anywhere in the discussion previously.
I only know this user is the closer because they're a prolific duplicate-finder in the python tag, and it can be seen in the history. It does not show in the banner.
My question is simple: does typing the @-mention comment manually like that reach close user(s) inbox/notification, or is it pointless to try?

How do comment @replies work? mentions "For questions: The non-moderator user who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the only one to do so"

...Yes, what is it?

@ipodtouch0218 Thank you. Actually shog9 answer, which I found 1 more click from there, is even better.

Meta SE has the FAQ entry on comment @replies. You can @-mention users if they were the only non-moderator user who voted to close a question (in 99% of cases this is a gold badge-wielder, but there are some exceptions, see below).
The FAQ says:

Who can be notified with this feature?
For questions: The non-moderator user who closed or reopened the question, provided they were the only one to do so. On most sites, this only includes users with gold tag badges who single-handedly closed or reopened duplicate questions. Other cases of this include closures/reopenings on Stack Overflow prior to 2009 and on Hardware Recommendations after mid-2019. If other users were also involved in the closure (e.g., closed by User1, User2, and GoldBadgeUser), no users can be notified.

A bit further down, an explanation for how the auto-complete feature works is available:

Why do some names not appear in the auto-complete box?
Only users who have commented on the post are populated into the list. Editors and other users from the post's history will never appear there, even if they are able to be notified by typing manually. The author is also not included unless they commented.

Karl did not have an undeleted comment on the question, therefore they do not appear in the auto-complete box. That said, your @-mention should've pinged them (had you spelled it correctly, anyway! You missed a K at the beginning of Knechtel).

Feature-request: the auto-completion choices should be 1:1 with the users who can be notified.

@wim 100% agreed. This was declined some time ago. It's been plenty long enough that reposting it and asking for a reconsideration about that decline would, probably, be fine.

"That said, your @-mention should've pinged them." - it didn't, because it was misspelled (a good reason to support that feature request!).

D'oh!   I retried with the correct spelling, does the system work as the answer claims, this time?
